# Cached data not clearing for PHP E-mail application form after completion

Tags: php, forms, caching

I have an application form which forwards submitted user details to a specified e-mail. All aspects of this form work fine.

There is, however, an option at the start of the form which asks if you want to add a joint applicant. This functions relies on replacing an array of data with another

```
if (isset($_SESSION['app1Title'])) {
$fields = array("app2Title", "app2FirstName", "app2Surname", "app2DOB", "app2Email", "app2Telephone", "app2Mobile", "app2MaritalStatus", "app2LicenceType");
define(TITLE,"Details about your joint applicant");
}
else {
$fields = array("app1Title", "app1FirstName", "app1Surname", "app1DOB", "app1Email", "app1Telephone", "app1Mobile", "app1MaritalStatus", "app1LicenceType", "rdoJointHirer");
define(TITLE,"Details about you");
}
```

However, after completing the form - attempting to begin a new application shunts you straight to 'joint applicant' rather than beginning from fresh

Here is the code for the actions after submission.

```
      // If everything is OK.
      if (empty($error)) {
          if (!isset($_SESSION['app1Title]'])) {
              foreach ($_POST as $key => $field)
                  $_SESSION[$key] = $field;

              if ($_POST['rdoJointHirer'] == "Yes") {
                  $_SESSION['return'] = "1";

                  header("Location: personal.php");
              }
            else
                header("Location: address.php");
        }
        else {
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $field)
            $_SESSION[$key] = $field;

            header("Location: address.php");
        }

        ob_end_clean();

        exit();
    }
    else {
        $values = post_values($fields); //Initialise all fields with their POST values
        require('forms/personal-form.php');
    }
}
}
else {
$values = blank_values($fields); //Initialise all fields as blank
require("forms/personal-form.php");
 }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Copying all `$_POST` parameters to session variables seems like a bad idea -- what if one of the POST parameters overwrites an internal session variable. You should only copy valid parameters.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Session variables persist from one run to the next, that's the whole point of them. If you want to reset the session, delete the session variables.